# Submit JQuery mobile form without redirect to php file

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I'm new to JavaScript and also the JQuery mobile framework is new to me.

I made a small form and after submitting I want to run JavaScript Code to check if all inputs are given. 
I found a lot of examples how to redirect to php files but I don't understand how I can run the JS Code and use the given input there ...

I tried to redirect to my JS Code using this line:

```
<form action="#" id="Form" onsubmit="return check()">
```

I defined the function check() but nevertheless the error message is that the variable check is not found ...
Hope someone can help me ...

---

I tried Ben Lee's approach but I don't understand why this is not working:

```
$('#Form').submit(function(ev) {
console.log("nice!!");
});
```

The button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

Comment: I added an update to my answer explaining why your new code snippet doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an `onsubmit` attribute. Instead attach an event (see http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Form').submit(function(ev) {
        if (!check()) return false;
    });
});
```

If you do it this way, you don't have to define a separate `check` function. You can just put the validation logic directly in the handler if you want. Which you decided to do depends on other implementation factors.

UPDATE: `$("#form1").submit(...)` does not work because "#form1" is not the right selector. When you use a selector of the form "#something" that looks for an element with an id attribute of "something". Since you form has `id='Form'`, you need to use `$('#Form')`.

Comment: This was not the problem, because I made a mistake while posting the code. I don't understand why this is not working ...

Comment: I had two different .html files for each page. Since a transfered the code from the second file to the first I dont't have the problem anymore.